# When is a temporary object created in a function argument supposed to be destroyed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, standards

## Short version

In this code :

```
QString dataStr;

myfunc(dataStr.toUtf8().constData());
```

Is the temporary QByteArray object created by toUtf8() destroyed before entering the scope of myfunc() or is it guaranteed to be destroyed after the call to myfunc() is finished?

## Long version

I am working with a code similar to this one :

```
class Request
{
public :
    std::function<void()> requestFunc;
};

void myfunc(const char* data)
{
    auto request = new Request();

    auto lambda = [](const std::string& str)
    {
        cout << str;
    }
    // Use data
    request->requestFunc = std::bind(std::move(lambda), std::string(data));
    requestQueue.push(std::move(request));
}

QString dataStr;

myfunc(dataStr.toUtf8().constData());

// Some time later, requestQueue gets managed and requestFunc gets called
```

One the machine of one of my coworkers, it crashed. We resolved this explicitly changing the scope of the temporary QByteArray object created by toUtf8() :

```
...
QString dataStr;

const QByteArray tempObj = dataStr.toUtf8();
myfunc(tempObj.constData());
```

And it resolved the crash. But later we a discussion with another coworker, and it isn't obvious to me if the C++ standard / the compiler is supposed to keep the temporary object until the function call is finished, or if its scope is limited to the parameter, and thus once inside *myfunc()* the temporary parameter object is already destroyed.

The two possibilities that I see that explain the "fix" of the crash :

- **The temp object is indeed destroyed before entering the function**, and constData() is pointing to freed memory. As not much happens before it is used, the memory is usually still holding the right value and has not been overwritten. That's why it was working most of the cases even being wrong, and **the new version is the correct fix**.
- **The temporary object is only destroyed after the function call is finished**. It means that the bug is elsewhere, and **the "fix" only** worked because we delayed the destruction of the temporary object, and thus **lowered the likelihood of freed memory being overwritten**.

If this is the latter case, than do you know where the bug might be laying?

**EDIT :**

It turns out the bug was with my previous code. Before the change I was doing this :

```
QString dataStr;
const char* dataPtr = dataStr.toUtf8().constData();
myfunc(dataPtr);
```

So the temporary object was being destroyed before the call to myfunc()

Comment: The temporaries are destroyed after the full-expression calling the function finishes (which is later than the function call returns).

Comment: `dataStr.toUtf8().constData()` -- You didn't test by assigning that whole thing to a variable and see what results you get.  If the contents of the variable in the crash machine are "messed up", then this really had nothing to do with the function call, but possibly something breaks down in the call chain.

Comment: Your question has likely at least one typo: `obj` should probably be `request`. If you don't show actually tested code, there is a huge risk that the actual code is different in some detail that seems minor to you, but actually changes the analysis.

Comment: Also neither `std::move(request)` nor `std::move(lambda)` make sense in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. This code isn't in my repository, I have little say in it. But I will try to see if I can get it fixed by the other team.
Yes, this is not the actual code. I figured I would have more chance of someone checking the problem if I did not include unnecessary details.

Comment: @user17732522 I've found out what was the real problem and edited my question to include that information.

Comment: If `.toUtf8()` is returning a destructed temporary, or `.constData()` is returning a destructed temporary, then the problem is in those routines that were not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the temporary QByteArray object created by toUtf8() destroyed before entering the scope of myfunc() or is it guaranteed to be destroyed after the call to myfunc() is finished?

The object is not a *parameter object*. It is a *temporary object*. A temporary object is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* in which it was created, although some exceptions apply, none of which is relevant to this example. Note that a *parameter object*, i.e. the object corresponding to a non-reference parameter of a function, is not a *temporary object* and follows other rules.

The end of the full-expression in your example is after the evaluation of `myfunc(dataStr.toUtf8().constData())`, i.e. at the end of the expression statement.

In your modified example in the question edit, the end of the full-expression in which `dataStr.toUtf8()`'s result object is materialized is after the initialization of the variable `dataPtr`, which means that in the following call `myfunc(dataPtr)`, the object is already destroyed and `dataPtr` is dangling.

Comment: So using dataStr.toUtf8().constData() is fine, and the bug lies elsewhere, right?

Comment: I've edited the title to be correct in light of your explanation

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães Yes, this is not the cause of the bug/UB.